# timeit import error (djangobook chapter 3, part2, python version 2.7.2)

Tags: python, django, import

I'm  trying to complete [Your second view: Dynamic Content](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/) of the Djangobook Chapter 3.

When I paste `http://localhost:8000/time/` in my browser I get the following error:

```
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Error: ImportError    
cannot import name current_datetime
Exception Location: /home/name/Desktop/sc/mysite/mysite/urls.py in <module>, line 2
python version 2.7.2
```

Yet my views.py and urls.py files are identical to the examples and in the right folders.

My views.py file

```
import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

My urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite.views import hello, current_datetime

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^hello/$', hello),
    ('^time/$', current_datetime),
)
```

What is going wrong here?

---

(ADDED to original post:)
(EDIT 1)
My directory structure. 
(with current working directory `/home/name/Desktop/sc/mysite`)

```
name@name-Studio-1558:~/Desktop/sc/mysite$ ls -R
.:
manage.py  mysite  views.py  views.py~

./mysite:
__init__.py   settings.py   urls.py   urls.pyc   wsgi.py
__init__.pyc  settings.pyc  urls.py~  views.pyc  wsgi.pyc
```

---

(EDIT 2)
I did the whole chapter from the beginning again using the name `mysite2` instead of `mysite`, I can't even get the first part to work now: Hello World.': 
[ImportError (djangobook chapter 3, part1, python version 2.7.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152956/importerror-djangobook-chapter-3-part1-python-version-2-7-2)

Before I changed something in the script to make it work, but I can't recreate what I had done before.

Comment: please check to ensure there is not the \__init\__.py file inside the first project mysite dir

Comment: Also, remember that the Django Book is for version 1.0. If you want to follow the tutorial for 1.4 go to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/

Comment: There is no __init__.py file in my first mysite folder.

Comment: As I added to my answer, both directories should contain init files. And there is something odd about other file layout too. Maybe try to re-create the project with commands 'startproject' and 'startapp' and add your views?

Comment: I also created a new __init__.py file in the first mysite folder. Still doesn't change anything. 

I made a new project mysite2. I get an error from following the first part of the chapter as well. I made a new stackoverflow entry:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152956/importerror-djangobook-chapter-3-part1-python-version-2-7-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that the djangobook is not up to date for django version 1.4. If you follow the chapter 3 correctly you will encounter errors. Certain files are created in different locations by default within the different versions of django.

See:
[ImportError (djangobook chapter 3, part1, python version 2.7.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152956/importerror-djangobook-chapter-3-part1-python-version-2-7-2/10153025#comment13022078_10153025)

So for the time being it is better to follow the django docs.

Comment: you should accept your answer if you could solve the problem this way.

Answer (score 1):

Change your urls.py to this (assuming your app is called *app*).:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^hello/$', 'app.views.hello'),
    (r'^time/$', 'app.views.current_datetime'),
)
```

Update: the base directory of your project should contan an empty `__init__.py` file too.

Comment: Try adding an empty `__init__.py`  file in your apps directory as moooeeeep suggested.