# ImportError (djangobook chapter 3, part1, python version 2.7.2)

Tags: python, django, import

I am following (http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter03/) Djangobook 2, chapter 3, subchapter 'Your First Django-Powered Page: Hello World'.

I get an ImportError, 'no module named views' (check url at the end of the post).

I am using Python 2.7.2

I will go through everything I did step by step:

```
$ pwd /home/name/Desktop/sc
$ django-admin.py startproject mysite2
$ cd mysite2

$ pwd /home/name/Desktop/sc/mysite2
$ ls -R
.:
manage.py  mysite2  views.py~

./mysite2:
__init__.py   settings.py   urls.py   urls.pyc  wsgi.pyc
__init__.pyc  settings.pyc  urls.py~  wsgi.py
```

Then I created `views.py` in `~Desktop/sc/mysite2`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

Then I went to `~Desktop/sc/mysite2/mysite2`.
I changed my `urls.py` to contain the following:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite2.views import hello

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^hello/$', hello),
)
```

Then I ran `python manage.py runserver` in ´/home/name/Desktop/sc/mysite2`.
When I paste`http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in my browser I get the following screen:

http://tinypic.com/r/23th72v/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** fully working with Django `1.4.0-final`

Overall, I'd recommend to re-do the `startproject` step and start over from scratch; I will summarize the steps you need to take:

**1) Create a new Django project**

```
$ django-admin.py startproject helloWorldProject
```

This creates a new folder `helloWorldProject` containing some stub files.

**2) Create a new file `views.py`** _*INSIDE*_ your `helloWorldProject/helloWorldProject` folder. It should contain the following code:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world")
```

**3) Update the `urls.py` file** (within the same folder as `views.py`):

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  url(r'^$', 'helloWorldProject.views.hello', name='hello'),
)
```

**4) Run your server** using the known command:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

This should give you some output similar to this

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4, using settings 'helloWorldProject.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

**5) Check if your "Hello World" view works** -- point your browser to http://127.0.0.1:8000/

**NOTE:** If you define an URL pattern like `('^hello/$', 'helloWorldProject.views.hello', name='hello'),`, you have to point your browser to http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/ as otherwise you will get an HTTP 404 error message...

Hope that helps :)

Comment: What is `$ PYTHONPATH=.. python manage.py runserver` known command? If you organize django project correct, you don't need to append anything to python path

Comment: "known" relative to the post history :P You can indeed omit the PYTHONPATH setting and it will still function; calm down...

Comment: Hmmm... I'm afraid it will confuse django beginners

Comment: I dropped mentioning of PYTHONPATH, focusing on the wrong folder structure and the how-to instructions; should be Django-beginner-friendly now...

Comment: I am trying to recreate your `helloWorldProject`. For step 2, do you create `views.py` in `/helloWorldProject` (folder that contains `manage.py`) or `/helloWorldProject/helloWorldProject` (folder that contains wsgi.py)? I assume in the folder that contains `manage.py`, because that is how its written in the djangobook chapter 3.
For step 3, you say "update" the url file in the SAME folder. But there is no `urls.py` file created by default in the helloWorldProject folder (the one that contains manage.py).

Comment: I'll refine the steps for Django 1.4; just a second :)

Comment: Thank you!!! You/I did it. It seems there were 2 things I needed to do differently to make it work:
I. I created my `views.py` file in the same folder as `wsgi.py` now instead of in the same folder as `manage.py`.
II. The content of the `urls.py` file had to be like your step 3. Strangely changing the `urls.py` file as shown in the djangobook is wrong(see my original post of `urls.py`). Why is this wrong?

Comment: Because, as @San4ez mentioned earlier, the Django book is outdated; it "Covers Django 1.0", and things are somewhat different in 1.4...

Comment: Before 1.4 version `manage.py` was located in the same folder with `settings.py` and `urls.py`. Now it is 1 level up

Comment: Thnx. That explains a lot of the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Django book describes old django version. Quote from [Chapter 2](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter02/)

> Official releases have a version number, such as 1.0.3 or 1.1, and the
>   latest one is always available at
>   http://www.djangoproject.com/download/.

In the newest 1.4 project layout was [updated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py), so be careful to use examples from that book. I advise you to try [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) from official documentation at first.

I assume you should create `views.py` in `~Desktop/sc/mysite2/mysite2` near `urls.py`